# Parϯner up and find the imposter!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, computer-puzzle

Messenger,

Our 5 top agents ѡill sօon arrive in diಽguise for the big meeting this weeĸ, and each has provᎥded their credentialઽ, but we've just received word one may be an imρostеⲅ sent by ouᴦ enemies.
Please dοuble check the attached credentials and cߋnfirⅿ who the infiltrator is before the meeting begins.

*We will catch them, it's a matter of when, not **ⅰf***

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| B |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| D |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| E |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| F |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| G |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| H |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| I |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| J |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

`Regards,`
`Administration`
`(01) 555 444 66`

Hint:

> If you are in ϯhe same area,  the parentҺeses in ɑ phone number indicaϯe ઽomething that is implicit - it caη be left οuϯ. If you ɑre outside the area, however, you may need to *add it back iη*. Also 555 ¡s not a clue, and can be ignored (It's just to make it a non-⨍unctional number).

Hint 2:

> 444 = 66, maybe I made this one a Ь¡ϯ too tricky.

PS: Apologies, I had intended to edit with another hint earlier, but have been knocked out with the flu.

However the bounty shakes out as a result, the first correct answer will get +100 even if I have to add a second bounty.

Comment: Can you add an image, please? Some symbols are not visible.

Comment: @ACB Nope, you don't need it 

Comment: I think ACB's point is that in some browsers ([e.g. Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX3dW.png)) your grid does not appear correctly, as emojis have cross-compatibility issues. You and your question may benefit from also posting a screenshot of what the emoji grid *should* look like. If 'you don't need it', then why bother including it in the puzzle? Please do consider your readers' user experience here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying not to give away too much, but the puzzle would be unsolvable using an image instead of the supplied grid.

Answer (score 4):

My small contribution:

Based on Jenia's post:

> The final character in "ⅰ" in "not ⅰf" is the only one that doesn't form part of the sentence. This makes it special.

If you...

> Check the unicode number of each of the symbols, all the ones I've checked start with "1F". For example,  corresponds to "U+1F39C". Given that "1F" is similar to "ⅰf", I think we need to remove the "1F" in front of the unicode numbers.

Following that...

> The hint states that we may need to add "01" back in, which would give us a new string of "0139C" for the  above. Some of these have unicode characters associated with them, but here is where I get lost. For example, the unicode symbol of U+0139C appears as ᎜ and it doesn't have much information associated with it.

Not sure if that is going to be helpful in the end, but we'll see!

Comment: Getting pretty close now :) 

Comment: Also, rot13(ⅰ vf gur Ebzna ahzreny sbe 1)

Comment: I'm honestly just mainly confused by the A-J & 0-9 grid, I'm trying to work out if the grid positions actually mean anything and if so, what I'm missing in the available clues to make sense of them.

Answer (score 4):

My guess (apologies on the formatting, first time responding on SE):

> Converting the character table to unicode gives us this:
>
> ```
>  | |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |
>  |A|1F101|1F39C|1F05C|1F4D4|1F150|1F714|1F3CF|1F706|1F052|1F709|
>  |B|1F39C|1F0CF|1F552|1F51C|1F70D|1F24B|1F15C|1F4D0|1F252|1F15C|
>  |C|1F1C1|1F31C|1F0C8|1F24C|1F313|1F70F|1F554|1F71C|1F1C1|1F085|
>  |D|1F70F|1F554|1F4C9|1F105|1F49C|1F415|1F51C|1F24E|1F704|1F241|
>  |E|1F34F|1F384|1F71C|1F345|1F31C|1F181|1F2C5|1F706|1F305|1F619|
>  |F|1F706|1F485|1F383|1F21C|1F550|1F701|1F08F|1F585|1F71C|1F4C1|
>  |G|1F35C|1F50F|1F3DC|1F0CF|1F396|1F3CC|1F554|1F144|1F70E|1F705|
>  |H|1F107|1F65C|1F18F|1F49C|1F508|1F15C|1F1D2|1F04D|1F71C|1F685|
>  |I|1F2C5|1F703|1F053|1F50C|1F15C|1F0C1|1F394|1F705|1F054|1F701|
>  |J|1F51C|1F3C4|1F11C|1F1C5|1F48D|1F04E|1F702|1F3C4|1F147|1F05C|
> ```

From academiaTA's response + admin's phone # + the hint:

> That's not an if -- omitting '01F' from the unicode values

From Jenia's response:

> Two skis per room is referring to the number 1 -- the cells of interest are the ones with exactly 2 1's.

So then:

> This gives us cells A0, C0, C8, E5, and J2 with agents 101, 1c1, 1c1, 181, and 11c, respectively
>  My initial guess is that 11C (J2) is the impostor, as it's the only one that doesn't follow the 1#1 pattern.  But I'm not totally sure why there's 2 1C1's, or how the 0, 4s, and 6s play into the puzzle (The numbers in the administration phone # and appearing in A0, D3, and H0).  C hex is 12, which is the sum of the 3 4's and 2 6's in the segments of the phone number.  This has me convinced that one of the 1C1's is the impostor.

Trying to eliminate one:

> Interpreting (01) <s>555</s> 444 66 as
>  (not) the one bound by (0), 4, 6
>  [image: Cell C0 surrounded]
>  I feel like I'm making a bit of a stretch.  But combined with the cell's coordinates (0,c) being hex for 12, I think that **Cell C0 is the impostor**

Comment: [Markdown tables aren't supported in spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359860/) (unfortunately). This is a case where you'll have to pursue less accessible options, such as [MathJax](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7421/), [preformatted text](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), or just images.

Comment: An interesting guess, rot13(Lbh ner evtug gung rnpu pryy vf n ebbz, ohg n fxv va guvf chmmyr vf abg n 1, vg'f whfg n fxv.)

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution yet, but here is what I found:

> If we'll take a look at the message we've got, we can find there non-ASCII characters (I used [this](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emarkm/ascii.html) site): *Par**ϯ**ner up and find the imposter! Messenger, Our 5 top agents **ѡ**ill s**օ**on arrive in di**ಽ**guise for the big meeting this wee**ĸ**, and each has prov**Ꭵ**ded their credential**ઽ**, but we've just received word one may be an im**ρ**ost**еⲅ** sent by ou**ᴦ** enemies. Please d**ο**uble check the attached credentials and c**ߋ**nfir**ⅿ** who the infiltrator is before the meeting begins. We will catch them, it's a matter of when, not **ⅰ**f.*

From this we can get:

> **ϯѡօಽĸᎥઽρеⲅᴦοߋⅿⅰ**. "Two Skisper room"?

Also I searched that phone number and looks like it belongs to some company (Ace Computers inc). Not sure if it's ok to add it to the challenge *if* it has nothing to do with the puzzle...

Comment: rot13(V guvax vg'f zber yvxryl 'gjb fxvf cre ebbz'. Gung'q nyfb xvaq bs nyvta jvgu gur chmmyr gvgyr bs 'cnegare hc')

Comment: Good start, if it helps at all I had no idea that was a real phone number... Please don't call and ask about the puzzle :P